Excel =IF formula using Today() as a date stamp, populating response in unwanted cells
In cell AA2 I am using the formula =IF(A2:Z2<>A2:Z2, "", TODAY())
This formula is supposed to update AA2 with today's date if any edits are made to cells A2 through Z2.  This works, but, it also populates the next 25 cells in the row with the equation.  The formula is not a dark black color in the top box as it normally would be but instead a subdued gray.  Only when the formula is activated does this occur, so if the row has no entries there is no date stamp or extra cells with a date stamp.
Is there a way to limit this formula to only being used and displayed in cell AA2?


It'd be much better to use VBA to write the date.

Is there a way to do this with VBA where each row can have its own independent updating of the Date Modified cell?  I have over 2000 rows I am working with

Very easily, using the Worksheet.Change event.

All of the AA cells are updating regardless of which row I update.  The formula has changed for each row, ie A3:Z3 - A4:Z4 etc.  any additional thoughts good sir

Since the formula will only be triggered to recalc by the commit of a cell and not the edit of a cell This will always return the current date as the cells will always equal them selves any time there is an edit anywhere on the sheet.  There is no way to do this with formula.  It will require vba

okay, I will do some more searching on a vba method.  Thank you both for clarifying

you're dealing with a SPILL formula; if you actually want to show today's date only once, then use UNIQUE (with a FILTER to take out the empty cell if it bothers you).  (also you won't know which cell is updated/different.)

I managed to solve this problem.  It required use of a VBA macro which also requires the excel document to be saved as .xlsm
First in the VBA editor I created a new module with the following code:
Sub UpdateTimeStamp()
Dim Target As Range
Dim targetRow As Long
Set Target = Range("A:Z")  ' Replace A:Z with your actual data range  
Set Target = Application.Intersect(Target, ActiveCell)
If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
targetRow = Target.Row
Worksheets("Data-Set").Cells(targetRow, 27).Offset(-1, 0).Value =  
Now 
End Sub

Next under the worksheet itself in the VBA editor I input the following code:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:Z")) Is Nothing Then 
UpdateTimeStamp 
    End If
End Sub

